# Is Bitcoin Core storage compatible across different machine architecture?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, raspberry-pi

I want to run Bitcoin core on a raspberry PI (arm32v7), but the initial sync takes way too long.

I am thinking importing the UTXO set from another of my node which run on x64.

Would it work? Is it safe to assume it will always work?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/62890/is-it-possible-to-transfer-blockchain-data-from-one-machine-to-another#comment72369_62890

Comment: It does not reply whether it should works across different architecture

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The database format is supposed to be compatible across architectures.